# Need help creating a work item in tfs 2015 using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, tfs, tfs-2015, azure-devops-rest-api

When I try to pass my json object for creating a task item and pass the content-type application/json-patch+json as well and the type PATCH i'm getting an erro: The request indicated a "Content-Type of \"\" for method type \"PATCH\" which is not supported. Valid content types for this method are application/json=patch+json. ".

It works fine when I call it in Postman with the same application type and type Patch. I'm trying to create a webpage and get this to call the service when I click a button on the form.

```
var newJson = '[{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.Title","value":"JavaScript implementation for Microsoft Account"}]';
var oJson = JSON.stringify(newJson);

//AZURE URL
var url = "https://dev.azure.com/AIZ-GL-dryrun/375977db-f390-4aac-bc4d-808f51360f9a//_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=5.1";

jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
url: url,
async: true,
data: oJson,
type:'PATCH',
contentType: "application/json-patch+json;",
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa(username+':'+password));
},
success: function(data){
    var myObject = JSON.stringify(data);
    alert("RESULT: "+myObject);
},
error: function(err) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(err))}
});
```

Comment: Is it Azure DevOps, or TFS 2015? The API versions are going to be wildly different between the two. TFS 2015 supported the 2.x series of REST APIs.

Comment: I'm using TFS2015

Answer (score 1):

As *Daniel* pointed out,  `var url = "https://dev.azure.com/AIZ-GL-dryrun/375977db-f390-4aac-bc4d-808f51360f9a//_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=5.1"`

[image]

You were trying to use API with version 5.1. As you can see, this version is not supported with Team Foundation Server 2015.

Need to use version 2.x on TFS 2015 and try again. More detail about api version, kindly take a look at this official link-- [REST API Versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rest-api-versioning?view=azure-devops)

---

**Update**, use post instead of patch and try again.

```
return $.ajax({
        url: "https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Bug?api-version=1.0",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("{user}:{password}"),
            "X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PATCH",
            "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(myData),
        async: false,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert(jqXHR.status + ': ' + errorThrown);
            },
        success: function (data) {
           // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
```

Another way, you could also use  Work item batch api instead:

For example:

```
http://[collection url]/_apis/wit/$batch?api-version=1.0
```

Body:

```
[
  {
    "method": "PATCH",
    "uri": "/ScrumStarain/_apis/wit/workItems/$Product Backlog Item?api-version=1.0",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"
    },
    "body": [
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "apip1"
      },
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/id",
        "value": "-1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "method": "PATCH",
    "uri": "/ScrumStarain/_apis/wit/workItems/$Task?api-version=1.0",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"
    },
    "body": [
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "apip2"
      },
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/id",
        "value": "-2"
      }

    ]
  }
]
```

More information, you can refer to: [Work item batch operations](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/batch)

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. I edited the url and tried it again. Yet i'm still getting the same error.... Any other tips to resolve this?var url = "https://dev.azure.com/AIZ-GL-dryrun/375977db-f390-4aac-bc4d-808f51360f9a//_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=2.2"

Comment: Hi  Mirooshidan Asokan，please use post instead of patch or use work item batch api. More details please kindly check my update reply